# Problems with the following regular expression in RegularExpressionValidator control

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have written the following regular expression. It should match only filenames or folder names that don't end in .aspx.

```
ValidationExpression=".*[^(\.aspx)]$"
```

But it does not work. So, kings of RegEx land, please help. I would also like to invalidate extensions such as .Aspx, .aSPx etc. ( I quickly learned that there are some differences between how .net and JScript treat regular expressions).

Can anyone help ?

Comment: from what I can tell this just matches that the last element in the line is a, s, p, x or a .

Comment: No. It matches one character that's not one of the following: ( . a s p x )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^abc]` means "match one character except a, b, or c". You don't want a negated character class, you want negative lookbehind:

```
ValidationExpression=".*(?<!\.aspx)$"
```

Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` as an option in `Regex.IsMatch` to make it case insensitive.

In JavaScript, where there is no negative lookbehind, you can use a less efficient version with negative lookahead:

```
ValidationExpression="^(?:(?!\.aspx$).)*$"
```

Comment: No. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind. You could instead assert that .*\.aspx$ does NOT match your string.

Comment: I am trying to get away just by setting the ValidationExpression.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is you're using a character class, so you've specified that the last character cannot be '(' or '\' or '.' or 'a' etc.

You need a negative look behind, so something like:

```
".*(?<!\.aspx)$"
```

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details.  The syntax may be slightly different in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

As Al pointed out, you're matching a character class instead of ".aspx". The regex you're looking for is:

```
.*(?<!.aspx$)
```

Comment: If i use this i get an exception from javascript, when it tries to use the regular expression.